# Find Active User's workstations

Tags: powershell, sccm

I have a task that involves finding workstations that users use. I have a list of about 1000 users. I know SCCM 2012 has a report you can enter in one user name and it will tell you what workstation they use.

But I can find a way to parse in a list of 1000 users and to get back a workstation for each user.

Is there way in PowerShell or in SCCM 2012 or combine the two? I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable Asset Intelligence and inventory TopConsoleUser.  You can then run or create a custom report of your Active computers which lists TopConsoleUser. Export that report and do a VLOOKUP with your 1000 users list within Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with a direct SQL query on the database. I don't have access to our DB at the moment as I'm not on site, but from memory it'd be something like:

```
SELECT Name0, User_Name0 FROM v_R_System WHERE User_Name0 IN (<copy and paste your list of users here>)
```

e.g.:

```
SELECT Name0, User_Name0 FROM v_R_System WHERE User_Name0 IN ('asmith', 'bsmith', 'csmith', 'dsmith')
```

Of course it would be quicker if you set up a temporary table with the user list, but this should do the trick.

Comment: Can you do that but instead of pasting a list of users prompt for a collection?

Comment: You should be able to, yes. If I had access to our DB I'd check and provide an example, but without that I'm afraid I couldn't with any degree of accuracy.

Comment: I have this Query that pulls a list of users from a security groups, is there a way I can link them to a workstation they last logged on to?
"select SMS_R_USER.ResourceID,SMS_R_USER.ResourceType,SMS_R_USER.Name,SMS_R_USER.UniqueUserName,SMS_R_USER.WindowsNTDomain 
from
SMS_R_User 
where 
SMS_R_User.SecurityGroupName = "Domain\\TestGroup""